# systemd socket activation, sd_listen_fds return 0 fd

Tags: c, sockets, systemd

I am writing a sample systemd service to test few things.
unfortunately, the test code is not working.
(i expected it to be simple ..)

$>cat test.socket

```
[Unit] 
Description=TEST-SERVICE
[Socket] 
ListenStream=5575 
Accept=yes
[Install] 
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

$>cat test@.service

```
[Unit] 
Description=TEST-SERVICE
Requires=test.socket

[Service] 
StandardInput=socket 
PIDFile=/var/run/test.pid 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/server_d     
Type=simple
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The server code looks like below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char buffer[255];       //Temporary buffer to read and write data
    int sockfd, newsockfd ; //File descriptor for Sockets
    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;    //Structure to hold Client details
    socklen_t cli_len;      //Client length

    int nfd = sd_listen_fds(0);
    if (nfd != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No or too many file descriptors received.\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "FD Count: %d.\n",nfd);
            exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = SD_LISTEN_FDS_START + 0;
```

The output comes when I connect to the service as below.

```
>telnet 15.218.114.55 5575 
Trying 15.218.114.55... 
Connected to 15.218.114.55. 
Escape character is '^]'. 
No or too many file descriptors received. 
FD Count: 0. 
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It looks to me like sd_listen_fds(0) is returning 0.
what could be the reason for it here?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 different ways a socket unit works. With `Accept=yes`, systemd will do the `bind()` and `listen()` calls for each `LISTEN...=...` socket, then wait  with `select()` on them all. Whenever there is a connection, a socket becomes ready, and systemd will do an `accept()` call on the socket connection, then pass the new socket fd to the service unit ready to use with read/write etc. Systemd then carries on waiting for new connections, and will start a new service with each of them similarly.

In this case the (template) service does **not** use `sd_listen_fds()`. If you have `StandardInput=socket`, then you can simply read/write fd 0.

The second type of socket unit has `Accept=no` (the default if not specified). Systemd will do the `bind()` and `listen()` calls for each `LISTEN...=...` socket, then wait with `select()` on them all. As soon as the first socket is ready, it will start the service once only and pass all the open socket file descriptors to it. This is where the `sd_listen_fds()` api comes in. It says how many socket file descriptors got passed. They start at 3 (`SD_LISTEN_FDS_START`).

The service application now has to find out which of the passed sockets was ready. Typically, there is only one `LISTEN` line in the socket unit, so only one fd is passed, and so it is easy (otherwise simply do a `select()`).

The service application now  has to do an `accept()` on the ready socket, and can then read/write to the new fd. Normally, it would also continue to wait for more connections on the listened-to sockets it was given, do more accepts, and so on.